# Microsoft Bot Framework: MissingMethodException when Microsoft.Bot.Connector is updated

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I want to add Active Learning to my chatbot which requires Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA 4.3.2 and above. Currently my bot uses version 4.2.2 for any Microsoft.Bot.Builder or Microsoft.Bot.Connector packages. To update Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA I also need to update my Microsoft.Bot.Builder and Microsoft.Bot.Connector packages to >= 4.3.2. When I update Microsoft.Bot.Connector to any version greater than 4.2.2 I am getting the following error in the VS output window when I try to run the chatbot in the Bot Framework Emulator.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Critical: Application startup exception

System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Bot.Connector.OAuthClient.set_EmulateOAuthCards(Boolean)'.
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core.ApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseBotFramework(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
at CBot.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) in C:\Users\X\Desktop\CBot\Startup.cs:line 136
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
```

I believe the exception is occurring when I call .UseBotFramework():

```
    129   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    130   {
    131    _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    132
    133    app.UseDefaultFiles()
    134        .UseStaticFiles()
    135        .UseBotFramework();
    136   }
```

I've seen in the [Microsoft.Bot.Connector documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.connector?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) that there
is now an OAuthClientOld class as well as an OAuthClient class. And the OAuthClientOld class has the EmulateOAuthCards property but the OAuthClient class doesn't, so maybe this changed after Microsoft.Bot.Connector 4.2.2. I'm not sure how I can fix this however given that I don't directly call OAuthClient. Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: After the application builds, does it show any warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure **all** your Bot packages are upgraded to 4.3.2.

Any/all of the below:

```
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs                   {4.3.2}         
Microsoft.Bot.Connector                         {4.3.2}         
Microsoft.Bot.Schema                            {4.3.2}         
Microsoft.Bot.Configuration                     {4.3.2}         
Microsoft.Bot.Builder                           {4.3.2}         
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core   {4.3.2}    
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Ai.QnA                    {4.3.2}
```